# Multiple instances of a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, class, smart-pointers

After discovering that I needed to `delete` any `new` pointers I create, I quickly realized that my project was full of memory leaks and I didn't even know it. So I was prompted to use smart pointers. However I have an issue when trying to create multiple instances of a smart pointer. I've created an SSCE to better explain this.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <memory>
#include "classa.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    std::unique_ptr<ClassA> classa; //<----- a smart pointer of a Class type
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "classa.h"
#include <QDebug>

QVector<ClassA*> classes;//<------ QVector that contains instances of ClassA
                                    //So I can retrieve them later based on an index.

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    classa = std::unique_ptr<ClassA>(new ClassA()); //<---- Created here
    classes.push_back(classa.get()); //<---- appended to the QVector
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//When the button is clicked, the program crashes when trying to qDebug
//because the first instance that was loaded in the QVector is no longer
//"valid." It stops being "valid" when I create the second instance of ClassA
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    classa = std::unique_ptr<ClassA>(new ClassA());
    classes.push_back(classa.get());

    qDebug() << classes.at(0);
}
```

Hopefully the above comments explain enough. The first solution that came to mind was to change my declaration in mainwindow.h to `std::unique_ptr<ClassA> *classa;` but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the smart pointer?

Really confused. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't store pointers in containers like `QVector`. That's just making everything difficult if you're not using any polymorphism. Just store `ClassA` directly. If you do need to store base class pointers, make a `QVector<std::unique_ptr<ClassA>`, or use [any of Qt's smart pointers](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/08/25/count-with-me-how-many-smart-pointer-classes-does-qt-have/).

Comment: Hello. The issue (I believe) is not how I choose to store them. I already tried your suggestion. It still made the first instance "invalid" and would crash any time I went near it. I even put the first instance in a `ClassA* variable` and when I called it later after making the second instance it crashed.

Comment: Thank you for writing up a piece of code. But... A) What has your problem to do with Qt? Nothing. You could have written up an example that does not involve Qt, class inheritance etc. B) *What is the actual problem?* Yes, it's right there in the code, but couldn't you *describe* it? Do we really have to figure out expected behaviour / observed behaviour from source?

Comment: A) Nothing, it has nothing to do with Qt. You are correct.
B) The problem (explained in the comments) is that my first instance of ClassA is "breaking" for lack of better words and crashes my program whenever I try to access is after making another instance. My EXPECTED behaviour is for the ClassA instances to behave like regular pointers, not behave like static members.

Comment: By extracting a dumb pointer from a smart pointer and stashing it for later, you defeat the purpose of the smart pointer.

Comment: Before I even added a smart pointer, I was using regular pointers. I was able to create multiple instances of ClassA with no issue. But when switching to a smart pointer, it stopped acting (fully) like a pointer. Is there nothing I can do to create multiple instances of ClassA and have the memory management benefits of a smart pointer?

Comment: There are lots of things, just not what you did. The whole point of a `unique_ptr` is for it to be *unique*. We don't really know what your real problem is. Why are you using pointers at all? We don't know. What purpose does `classa` serve? We don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the core of your confusion is about what `std::unique_ptr<>` actually *does*.

From your MainWindow constructor:

```
classa = std::unique_ptr<ClassA>(new ClassA());
```

`classa` is now (smartly) pointing to `ClassA` instance #1. **If that memory reference goes out of scope, the memory will be deleted, avoiding a memory leak.**

```
classes.push_back(classa.get());
```

`classes[0]` now holds a (dumb) pointer to instance #1.

From your button click event handler:

```
classa = std::unique_ptr<ClassA>(new ClassA());
```

`classa` is now (smartly) pointing to `ClassA` instance #2.

**By assigning a new value to `classa`, the old one went out of scope. The memory allocated for instance #1 is now *deallocated*. That is the *purpose* of a smart pointer.**

`classes[0]` still holds a (dumb) pointer to the memory  *previously* held by instance #0. (You see where this is going, don't you?)

```
classes.push_back(classa.get());
```

`classes[1]` now holds a (dumb) pointer to instance #2.

```
qDebug() << classes.at(0);
```

Undefined behaviour, you die.

---

If you have your memory managed by smart pointers -- as you should -- **have** it managed by smart pointers. Don't `.get()` the dumb pointers out of them and store them elsewhere.

---

Since your example does not tell us what the `classes` vector should be *used* for, it's hard to give proper advice at this point.

- You can use `vector< ClassA >` to store instances of `ClassA` directly.
- You can use `vector< std::shared_ptr< ClassA > >` to store smart pointers and *also* use them elsewhere.(*)

Or...

- You could tell us about the actual *problem* you are trying to solve, and we can tell you what the best container would be. ;-)

---

(*):

`std::shared_ptr<>` is the more powerful sibling of `std::unique_ptr<>`. Unique pointers are *unique*, they cannot be copied. On the upside, they are just as efficient as "normal" pointers that you `delete` manually.

`std::shared_ptr<>` adds a (tiny) bit of bookkeeping, i.e. the number of copies that exist (as it *can* be copied), and only deletes the memory if the *last* copy of the smart pointer goes out of scope.

Either *relies* on you *not* storing (and using) the *dumb* pointer they contain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand the role of a smart pointer better now. Let me test some things out

Comment: @mc360pro: That's the problem I meant when commenting on your code example: It contains quite some code unrelated to the problem, *but does not really display the problem*. You want your `MainWindow` to hold a `ClassA` object, but *also* store (a reference to) that object in a (globally visible) vector. That's breaking data encapsulation, i.e. poor design, and we don't even know *what you want to achieve with it*. Your problem is not only about smart pointers; you're trying to solve an unrelated problem, and probably in a sub-optimal way. ;-)

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for your advice. For whatever reason I was under the impression that in order to create multiple instances of an object in a class it had to be declared as a pointer. Wow. This makes everything much easier. Sorry for the trouble and confusion and thank for your (and everyone else's) time :)

Comment: @mc360pro: No problem, that's what we're here for. ;-)

Comment: @mc360pro: Trust in one thing. Done right, C++ is *easy*. If you feel something is over-your-head difficult, that's either because the *problem* you're trying to solve is over-your-head (i.e., not the fault of the language), or you're trying to solve it the wrong way (i.e., you haven't learned that particular piece of the language yet, ask). There are few languages around for which I would make this particular claim. ;-)

Comment: Yeah I always tell myself that so I end up working all day on one thing only to later have someone tell me that I am misunderstanding one of the core mechanics of the language XD. Sorry bout that

Answer (score 2):

```
classa = std::unique_ptr<ClassA>(new ClassA()); //<---- Created here
classes.push_back(classa.get()); //<---- appended to the QVector
```

Don't do this. If you're going to use a `unique_ptr` to manage the lifetime of an object, don't store other pointers to the object in other places. If you do, as soon as the `unique_ptr` goes away, those other pointers are left dangling.

You don't really state your outer problem, but whatever it is, the approach of having a `unique_ptr` and also storing dumb pointers to the same object is asking for trouble. Not using pointers may be the better approach if you don't have a slicing issue. If you do, either keeping only one pointer or using a `shared_ptr` is probably the solution.

Why do you need pointers at all? What's the issue with values?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using pointers because I need multiple instances of the ClassA object. Normally, I would put `ClassA *classa` in my header file and then create `new` instances from that.

Comment: Why do you need pointers to have multiple instances? Why can't you do, for example: `std::vector<SomeClass> j; j.push_back(1); j.push_back(2);`? What purpose do the pointers serve?

Comment: I thought that all instances of the class share the static variables

Comment: The static variables aren't associated with any instance of the class. What does that have to do with pointers? Also, what is "the issue"? What purpose does `classa` serve? Why does it exist at all?

Comment: @mc360pro: Your example does not **have** static variables...?!?

Comment: Yeah I know because I thought having static variables was a bad thing for multiple instance classes. I'm dumb.

Answer (score 2):

You should read some more about smart pointers in general, what they are and how they work.
The short version regarding `unique_ptr` is this: the wrapped object is destroyed and the memory is deallocated when either of two things happens:

1. the `unique_ptr` itself is destroyed (e.g. by going out of scope)
2. the `unique_ptr` is assigned another object (by `operator=` or `reset()`).

In your case, things happen like this:

- you're creating an object and assigning it to the `unique_ptr` in the constructor
- you're also storing a raw pointer to that object in the vector
- later, in your button click handler, you create and assign a new object to the `unique_ptr`
- this causes the previous object to be destroyed
- at this point, the pointer you stored in the vector is dangling, it's pointing to a destroyed object

This succession of steps is repeated each time your click handler gets called: you create and store a new object in the `unique_tr`, which causes the previous one to be destroyed, which means your vector will contain only dangling pointers (except the last one).

This should be enough information to get you started towards a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I think I understood the action of events causing the issue, I was looking for a solution. I want a way to create multiple instances of ClassA WITH the memory benefits of a smart pointer. Is this not possible?

Comment: Without knowing why you need a pointer, I don't think anyone's going to be able to give you a useful answer. Why not just use values? What purpose do the pointers serve?

Comment: @mc360pro: try to store `unique_ptr`s in the vector instead of raw pointers. For this you'll have to understand move semantics and the single ownership model that `unique_ptr` implements. Or start with a shared ownership smart pointer (e.g. `shared_ptr`), make your code work with that, and then try to go back to the single ownership model and make that work. And always be careful about mixing smart pointers and raw pointers to the same object.